# Unable to change the styling properties inside an iframe body tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, styles

[image]I have written this html script to display wikipedia inside iframe but i want to change the background color of it, below is the code snippet which i tried. but its not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html> 

<head> 
<style>

    body {
        background-color: blue !important;
       /* Adding !important will give this rule more precedence over inline style */
    }



</style>

  

</head> 

<body> 

<iframe style="background-color:#fc3 !important;" src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" width="100%" height="450px" > 
</iframe>
 
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: you write something wrong. see background-color in iframe

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the contents of an iframe before loading (using CSS), because it is displaying content from another page. After it loads, you may modify it with javascript.

Comment: Hi Ian, May i know how it can be modified with javascript. do you have any sample code?